# Validate the Equality of 2 dictionaries with list values

Tags: python, python-3.x

if I have dictionaries like :

```
a = {"param":["a","b","c"],"b":"aaa","c":"aAAaFfa"}
b = {"param":["a","b","c"],"b":"aaa","c":"aAAaFfa"}
```

and I need to validate they are equal and return true or false neglecting the case sensitivity

I have already tried :

```
shared_headers = {k: a[k] for k in a if k in b and a[k].lower() == b[k].lower()}
return len(shared_headers) == len(a)
```

but it only works fine when the dicts have no list values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `''.join` - it can take any iterable of strings:

```py
shared_headers = {k: a[k] for k in a if k in b and ''.join(a[k]).lower() == ''.join(b[k]).lower()}
return len(shared_headers) == len(a)
```

Note: this will think `'abc'` is the same as `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Or, you could just compare the lowercase of the dicts:

```py
return str(a).lower() == str(b).lower()
```

Comment: What if the list contains something else than string like integers?

Comment: @mickcorjj Then use the alternative solution I gave - `str(a).lower() == str(b).lower()`

Comment: it gives false even if they are equal 
a = {"param":[1,"b","c"],"b":"aaa","c":"aAAaFfa"}
b = {"param":[1,"b","c"],"b":"aaa","c":"aAAaFfa"}
this gives false but they are equal

Comment: @mickcorjj I tried that and it gave `True`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this quite long (but with comments) code. It gets the type of the dictionary values in order to adapt the comparison algorithm:

```
def check(a, b):
    # Check if they have the same keys
    if set(a) != set(b):
        return False
    # Check if they have the same values (neglecting the case sensitivity)
    for k in a:
        if isinstance(a[k], str):
            # Here: value is a string
            if not isinstance(b[k], str):
                return False
            if a[k].lower() != b[k].lower():
                return False
        elif isinstance(a[k], list):
            # Here: value is a list
            if not isinstance(b[k], list):
                return False
            if len(a[k]) != len(b[k]):
                return False
            for i,j in zip(a[k],b[k]):
                if str(i).lower() != str(j).lower():
                    return False
        else:
            # Here: value is something else
            print("Unexpected")
            return False
    return True
```